# Capture FFMPEG output

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I need to read the output from ffmpeg in order to even try the solution to [my question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106955/php-and-ffmpeg-performing-intelligent-video-conversion).  This is a separate issue from my problem there, so I made a new question.

How the heck do I get the output from an `ffmpeg -i` command in PHP?

This is what I've been trying:

```
<?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $src = "/var/videos/video1.wmv";
    $command = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $src;
    echo "<B>",$command,"</B><br/>";
    $command = escapeshellcmd($command);

    echo "backtick:<br/><pre>";
    `$command`;

    echo "</pre><br/>system:<br/><pre>";
    echo system($command);

    echo "</pre><br/>shell_exec:<br/><pre>";
    echo shell_exec($command);

    echo "</pre><br/>passthru:<br/><pre>";
    passthru($command);

    echo "</pre><br/>exec:<br/><pre>";
    $output = array();
    exec($command,$output,$status);
    foreach($output AS $o)
    {
            echo $o , "<br/>";
    }
    echo "</pre><br/>popen:<br/><pre>";
    $handle = popen($command,'r');
    echo fread($handle,1048576);
    pclose($handle);
    echo "</pre><br/>";
?>
```

This is my output:

```
<B>/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/videos/video1.wmv</B><br/>
backtick:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
system:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
shell_exec:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
passthru:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
exec:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
popen:<br/>
    <pre></pre><br/>
```

I don't get it.  `safe_mode` is off.  There's nothing in `disable_functions`.  The directory is *owned* by `www-data` (the apache user on my Ubuntu system).  I get a valid status back from `exec()` and `system()` and running the same command from the command line give me tons of output.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is you catch only *stdout* and not *stderr* (see [*Standard Streams*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)).
Change this line:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $src;
```

into

```
$command = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $src . " 2>&1";
```

and give it another try :)

Comment: Ahhh... yeah.  That makes sense because my return status is 1 (not 0).  I wish that worked, but I still get the same result, just with: "<B>/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/videos/video1.wmv 2>&1</B>" at the beginning.  I'll do some research to see if Ubuntu has some differences for redirecting stderr.

Comment: I can confirm that the following should work. I've used this exact line in a hobby project once.

exec('ffmpeg -i ' . escapeshellarg($filepath) . ' 2>&1', $output);

Comment: Ahha!  I figured it out.  My problem was the escapeshellcmd() function.  It was changing "2>&1" to "2\>\&1".  I tried your code and it worked.  Lesson I've learned: output the command *after* you've made all modifications to it =p.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use ffprobe instead, it's much quicker and supports JSON output.

```
$output = shell_exec('ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "path/to/yourfile.ext"');
$parsed = json_decode($output, true);
```

And you have all your video info in a php array!  This is much faster than ffmpeg -i for some reason.

Comment: Wow, what a useful function! I had no idea this existed. Thank you!

Comment: It is also much quicker than initializing ffmpeg every time!

Answer (score 4):

To get output status and output:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4 2>&1", $output, $returnStatus);

print_r($output);

if($returnStatus === 0){
   // success
}
else {
   //fail
}
```

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiiiceeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec and print_r the output...

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4 2>&1",$output);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```